# Mongoose save method doesn't forget last schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I have this method to update a document

```
static updateData(data: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        nudgesDB.find({ _id: data.id }, (err, nudge: any) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            nudge = nudge[0];
            if (data.isRead) {
                nudge.isRead = data.isRead;
            }
            if (data.isDelivered) {
                nudge.isDelivered = data.isDelivered;
            }
            // if (data.deliveryResult) {
            //     if (nudge.deliveryResult && nudge.deliveryResult.length > 0) {
            //         nudge.deliveryResult.push(data.deliveryResult[0]);
            //     } else {
            //         nudge.deliveryResult = data.deliveryResult;
            //     }

            // }
            nudge.save( (error: any, updatedNudge: any) => {
                if (error) return reject(error);
                resolve(updatedNudge);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I'm trying to pass a new deliveryResult structure which is an array but for some reason deliveryResult for the first time still has the old schema in it
even after I commented out the code still it saves deliveeryResult

here is the schema for my collection:

```
const nudgesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    sourceId: String,
    registererGUID: String,
    createdTime: Date,
    originationDateTime: Date,
    expiryDateTime: Date,
    source: Object,
    title: String,
    target: String,
    sendTo: String,
    isRead: Boolean,
    isPush: Boolean,
    isDelivered: Boolean,
    bodyType: String,
    body: {
        message: String,
    },
    priority: Number,
    intent: Object,
    deliveryResult: Object
});
```

Any idea why is it like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .lean() so that it will return a pure object result from mongo, then you can edit its result.

```
static updateData(data: any) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    nudgesDB.find({ _id: data.id }).lean().exec((err, nudge: any) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
        nudge = nudge[0];
        if (data.isRead) {
            nudge.isRead = data.isRead;
        }
        if (data.isDelivered) {
            nudge.isDelivered = data.isDelivered;
        }
        // if (data.deliveryResult) {
        //     if (nudge.deliveryResult && nudge.deliveryResult.length > 0) {
        //         nudge.deliveryResult.push(data.deliveryResult[0]);
        //     } else {
        //         nudge.deliveryResult = data.deliveryResult;
        //     }

        // }
        nudgesDB.update({sourceId: nudge.sourceId}, {$set: nudge}).exec((err, updatedNudge) => {
            if (error) return reject(err);
            resolve(updatedNudge);
        })
    });
});
```

}

Comment: The update part of the code was also change since the nudge is not a mongo object anymore, so nudge.save() will not work..

Comment: Still the same I did console.log(nudge) before update and still it has deliveryResult in it with old schema